# Can two spin 0 particles be entangled?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, quantum-entanglement

Imagine that I have some kind of collision between two spin-0 particles that conserves the number of spin-0 particles, and I divide my lab in half with detectors on both sides called left L and right R. Could I have a final state where both particles end in opposite sides, written as

$$ |\psi\rangle=( |LR\rangle- |RL\rangle)/\sqrt2 $$
Where the first letter indicates the detector that detects particle 1 and the second letter the detector of particle 2. If I detect particle 1 on the right, I know particle 2 went left.

Of course, the experiment has to be done with different types of particles (this is not possible with identical particles). Also I am not assuming elementary particles, this could be two composite particles.

If that state $|\psi\rangle$ is possible then there is no way to test if it is indeed an entangled state or some complicated mechanics that simulates its results. Note that a Bell measurement is not possible as one cannot rotate the basis to do different measurements as these are spin-0 particles.

So is this state possible in principle?

Comment: The title of your question does not really fit the body of your question - you're asking about a very specific entangled state (one that one might use for Bell measurements), but there are *many* other entangled states (the set of non-entangled states has measure zero in the space of all states).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operator that'd check if the particle is on the left or the right can be written as $(1/2)\vert L\rangle\langle L\vert - (1/2) \vert R \rangle\langle R\vert$. Now, the same unitary transformations that takes $\sigma_z$ to $\sigma_{x,y}$ would take this operator to two other operators that don't commute with the original operator (as well as with each other). Using these two operators, you can perform all the Bell measurements you want. It doesn't matter that the particle is not spin$-1/2$. Sure, it would mean that these operators won't physically correspond to the generators of rotations, but their algebra simply doesn't change.

Comment: Oh right! I did not thought about the detectors. Is this the same as keeping one detector fixed and moving the other detector around? Say up down, diagonal and so on... That will account for other measurements ?

Comment: @Mauricio No, that's not what it would mean. I don't know what kind of physical set-up would realize the measurements of the other two operators I mentioned. You see, it would be an operator whose eigenstates are equal superpositions of $L$ and $R$. So, it wouldn't be any simple (or physically interesting) operator.

Comment: The point is, once you have a two level system, you can always construct the whole Pauli algebra and show that the system has all the same properties as a spin-half particle. But the formal operators you'd use to show this (while technically observables) won't usually correspond to any practical measurement one performs in a lab -- unlike the actual spin-half particle where the Pauli operators actually correspond to the measurement of spin along mutually orthogonal axes.  [...]

Comment: Imagine that the lab is a sphere with a Cartesian frame x,y,z. Where left, means to be measured with positive x and right, to be measured with negative x coordinate. Then I could measure projections in different axis to do a Bell test. Would that work?

Comment: [...] A nice example of how formal such manipulations are is the fact that for the two-level system of the Schrodinger cat (spanned by the alive state and the dead state), there exists an operator that whose measurement would turn the dead cat into a superposition of dead and alive which can further be measured by the operator that checks whether the cat is alive or dead to bring the cat back to life with $1/2$ probability. So there is a $1-1/2^N$ chance that you'd bring the dead cat back to life within $N$ repetitions of this procedure. ;)

Comment: @Mauricio No, the state you wrote can be subjected to the Bell procedure only using the algebra of operators that I wrote and as I said, they simply don't correspond to any directly conceivable laboratory arrangement of measuring simply their positions. These are operators that do not commute with the position operator.